# Hashicorp Vault: Python hvac does not see secrets

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault, vault, hvac

I'm trying to use `HashiCorp Vault` with `hvac` Python client.

I've run vault docker container (development mode config) on localhost, created a KV secret engine `kv1` (with version 1 API), added a secret `mega_secret`, added a key/value (`"hell" --> "yeah"`) it it and tried to read it with `hvac`.

At first, let's go to docker container terminal and check that the secret is alive:

```
# vault kv get kv1/mega_secret
==== Data ====
Key     Value
---     -----
hell    yeah
```

And now I'm trying to read it with `hvac`.

```
import hvac

client = hvac.Client(url="http://localhost:8200", token="hvs.4MzADdB9pIHAggqaQWQZASx0", namespace="")
assert client.is_authenticated()
assert not client.sys.is_sealed()

print(client.kv.v1.read_secret(path="kv1/mega_secret"))  # Here will be crash
```

Error message:

```
hvac.exceptions.InvalidPath: no handler for route "secret/kv1/mega_secret". 
route entry not found., on get http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/kv1/mega_secret
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Your KVv1 secrets engine is not mounted at one of the defaults: `secret`. Execute `vault serets list` to check where it is mounted.

Comment: Judging from the command line, it is mouted at `kv1`. I assume it is a version 1 kv store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vault can mount the same secret engine multiple times, each on its own mount point. You have chosen to use `kv1`, no problem with that.

HVAC assumes that [`secret` is the name of the mount point](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/hvac_api_secrets_engines.html#hvac.api.secrets_engines.KvV1.read_secret) by default.

You will be able to read your secret by specifying the mount point like this:

```
client.kv.v1.read_secret(mount_point="kv1", path="mega_secret")
```

Comment: Also was facing same issue, but I had to also mention namespace in the Client method for things to work.                                                                                          `client = hvac.Client(
    url='http://127.0.0.1:8200',
    token='dev-only-token',
    namespace='admin',  # If namespace is configured, make sure to set here
)`